# how do i set the time in php?

Tags: php, date

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Spain/Madrid");

$date=date("H:i:s");

echo $date;
?>
```

how can i set the date to my location?

i get this when i run the script Notice: date_default_timezone_set() [function.date-default-timezone-set]: Timezone ID 'Espana/Madrid' is invalid

i know Spain/Madrid is not recognized, but how can i fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");
```

Answer (score 2):

I typically use ini_set() :

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Madrid');
```

Answer (score 1):

try `Europe/Madrid`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the list of the supported timezones in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Answer (score 0):

[Here are the supported time zones in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
   $date=date("H:i:s");
   echo $date;
?>
```